# Why docker-daemon is not accessible in minikube VM?

Tags: docker, minikube, docker-build

I have installed minikube and started it with it's default virtual machine so basically started the minikube with `minikube start`. In minikube vm which i have accessed through `minikube ssh` i am trying to build my dockerfile after mounting the local file system but it's showing error `Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?`

I checked the `ActiveState` of docker through `systemctl show --property ActiveState docker` and it's showing failed but the `docker version` is showing me all the normal details like version built etc.

This is the statement that i am trying to execute : `$ sudo docker build --file=Dockerfile --tag=demo-backend:latest --rm=true .`

Should i install docker seperatley and if not how should access docker in VM  which is already present in my system

Comment: @d4nyll but minikube already comes binded with docker. why do i need to install docker again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like somehow docker has not started properly.

Please try to execute `sudo systemctl start docker` and let me know if that was the issue.

EDIT:
Adding more info from the comments in order to supplement the answer:

> I had to set the docker environment variable to local instance of
>   docker running in minikube through this command: eval $(minikube
>   docker-env) and then restart the docker and all of this has to done in
>   the same shell in which i aim to access the docker otherwise it does
>   not works. this made me acces the docker from minikube – rehan

Comment: to an extent, but majorly i had to set the docker environment variable to local instance of docker running in minikube through this command: `eval $(minikube docker-env)
` and then restart the docker and all of this has to done in the same shell in which i aim to access the docker otherwise it does not works. this made me acces the docker from minikube